# Could not parse the remainder: '(audio_only=True)'

Tags: python, django, django-templates

in my `templates/videos.html`,

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-3 gap-2">
    {% for vid in videos.streams.filter(audio_only=True) %}
        <a href="{{vid.url}}">{{vid.resolution}}</a>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Error is,

```
Could not parse the remainder: '(audio_only=True)' from 'videos.streams.filter(audio_only=True)'
```

I can solve this when i pass `all_videos = videos.streams.filter(audio_only=True)` from my `views.py` as context, and in `templates/videos.html` i replace `videos.streams.filter(audio_only=True)` with `all_videos`,

but I want to know that is there any other method to solve this

Comment: You can not make function calls of subscrip t in Django templates.

Comment: You will need to create the filtered queryset in the view.

Comment: You can do it by creating separate template tag but i would not recommend that because it can be done in views simply. Why do you wanna do it in template i don't see any use case.

Answer (score 0):

> but I want to know that is there any other method to solve this.

You could add an extra property/method with no parameters to the `Video` model and call that property to obtain the filtered queryset.

For example:

```
class Video(models.Model):
    # …
    
    @property
    def audio_streams(self):
        return self.streams.filter(audio_only=True)
```

and then thus use `{% for video in videos.audio_streams %}`. But regardless, the Django template language has been deliberately restricted to prevent people from writing this: a template should implement *rendering* logic, not *business* logic: business logic belongs in the models and the views. So the only clean solution is to filter in the *view*, not the template.